# Filtering a pandas dataframe by aggregating on two columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe. Here are the first five rows:

```
      InvoiceNo StockCode                          Description  Quantity      InvoiceDate       UnitPrice  CustomerID         Country  
    0    536365    85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   2010-12-01 08:26:00       2.55     17850.0  United Kingdom  
    1    536365     71053                  WHITE METAL LANTERN         6   2010-12-01 08:26:00       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
    2    536365    84406B       CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER         8   2010-12-01 08:26:00       2.75     17850.0  United Kingdom
    3    536365    84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE         6   2010-12-01 08:26:00       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
    4    536365    84029E       RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.         6   2010-12-01 08:26:00       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
```

I would like to group by `StockCode` and `CustomerID`, and sum `Quantity`. Then, I'd like to throw out all of the `StockCode`/`CustomerID` pairs where this sum is negative. The desired final product is the original dataframe with the rows corresponding to these StockCode/CustomerID pairs removed.

I have a working solution:

```
retail_df.groupby(['CustomerID','StockCode']).filter(lambda x: x['Quantity'].sum() >= 0)
```

However, it takes my laptop four minutes to run it. There are 406829 rows. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Could you put up a print(df) of the original data frame and show the output expected as well

Comment: I included the result of df.head(). You mean more rows? It would be hard to show expected output since there will be around 400k rows. I want the remove all rows belonging to a CustomerID/StockCode pair whose sum over Quantity is negative. For example, if I isolate all the rows where CustomerID==17850.0  and StockCode==71053, and the sum of all Quantity is negative, I do not want any of these rows to appear in the result.

Comment: Is it the `groupby()` or the `filter()` that's taking longest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
df2=retail_df.groupby(['CustomerID','StockCode'])["Quantity"].sum().ge(0)

retail_df=retail_df.set_index(['CustomerID','StockCode']).loc[df2.loc[df2].index].reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: It certainly did. Why is your solution so much faster?

Comment: Glad to hear:) main reason is - this solution is vectorized, it's not processing row-by-row. Second thing is - it's using ```pandas``` implementations for every method e.g. try using ```>=0``` instead of ```.ge(0)``` you should see it being a bit slower then.

Comment: Interesting. I agree that vectorization is the main reason, since using >= versus .ge() doesn't make a noticeable difference. So is the reason basically that the .filter() method is just really slow compared to .loc[]?

Comment: Yes - definitely. As for the ```.ge(...)``` I think it really depends on the dataset size - I noticed meaningful differences using ```.ge(...)```, ```.sub(...)```, ```.mul(...)``` etc. Vs ```>=```, ```-```, ```*``` for larger datasets and/or for more complex calculations. I think in principle it's a good approach to rather use a function (if provided), if it does the same as any math operator, since if operator would be faster, or at least as fast, no one would make a function in the first place ;) so usually these functions are there to provide more native way of doing basic stuff ;)